# How to lay last row of Hardwood Flooring under an undercut the Baseboard?

Tags: flooring

I've (almost) decided to undercut my baseboards before installing a hardwood floor.  For the last row of planks, how do I get them under the undercut baseboard, i.e. won't the second to last row interfere due to the height? What's the trick?

Edit: This is not a floating floor.

Comment: Is this a floating floor install?

Comment: For Fresh Codemonger: This is not a floating floor.

Comment: When I did one of my floors, I removed the baseboards, then put them back after the floor was down.

Comment: For SteveSh: yes, I understand that's an option.  It's not how I'd prefer to do it if I can avoid it.  I know it can be done with undercut baseboards. I'm sitting in a room where that was done.  But I didn't witness the process!  :)

Comment: Would it be possible to slide it in from a doorway opening, going under the molding?  For example, say your floor planks are 3" wide and 3' long.  Is it possible to slip the 3" end under the molding at a doorway and gently tap it down along the wall until it's where it needs to be?

Comment: For SteveSh: Possibly, at least in some locations.  Thank You for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll keep guessing.

If this is nail down with no tongue and groove then you slide the piece in and then use a glazer's bar to pry it back out while you nail it.

If this is tongue and groove nail down or glue down then

1. quarter round
2. or micro-round
3. or cut the tongue off the last piece and glue to avoid face nail.
4. or cut the tongue off, create a biscuit, glue the biscuit and pry the last piece back onto the biscuit and glue this piece down to avoid face nail.

If you don't want 1/4 or micro round your option seems to be either 3 or 4.

Comment: This is tongue and groove nail down.  I don't want to use quarter round. I want to get the edge of the plank inside of the edge of the undercut baseboard.  My concern is how do I get that last piece *under* the baseboard?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Choose a straight piece of flooring for the last row. The cuts shown are what I typically make for the floor go in as you need. Drill pilot holes before you set the floor in place. Angle them slightly so the process of driving the nail keeps the joint tight. Be certain you size the holes right. The shanks should just fit through, and the head of the nail not. Get this right, use a drill bit to the 1/32" increment to get it right.

Set the piece in, using glue at the tongue if you choose too. Place the nails in the pre-drilled holes, and use the nails to pull the floor into place. Tap the piece to vibrate it if needed, it really helps moving tight pieces. Set your nails and countersink them.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I think this is just what I needed!